# A problem with notation on B. Maccluer's book

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm studying Banach algebras and I'm confused by the following statement:

> Let $\mathcal{A,B}$ be Banach algebras with common identity and suppose $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$

What does that mean? As far as I understand, it is the same as "let $\mathcal{B}$ be a subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$ that contains the identity element". Does the statement also imply that $\mathcal{B}$ is a closed (topologically speaking) subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$?

Also, in the exercises it says "Let $\mathcal{A,B}$ be Banach algebras with common identity and suppose $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ and let $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Prove that $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(B)\subset\sigma_\mathcal{B}(B)$ and $\partial\sigma_{\mathcal{B}}(B)\subset\partial\sigma_\mathcal{A}(B)$." Even though the first inclusion is easy and true without $\mathcal{B}$ being necessarily a closed subalgebra, I can't prove the second one without the implication that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed and the only thing I found here is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679830/boundary-of-a-spectrum-proof) (that also uses a closed subalgebra).

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subspace of a  Banach space which is complete is closed. A Banach algebra is complete so $\mathcal B$ is closed.

Comment: I guess you're right! Thanks, you saved me from a confusion. So the statement as stated ( $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{A}$ and they have the same identity) is equivalent to $\mathcal{B}$ is a closed subalgebra of $\mathcal{A}$ containing the identity, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.