# Spectrum invariance under the passage to a $C^*$ sub-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal B(E)$ be a  $C^*$ sub-algebra inside the algebra of bounded operators in a Hilbert space $E$,with $I\in \mathcal A$. For $T\in \mathcal A$,let $\sigma(T)$ denote the spectrum (as an element of $\mathcal B(E)$) and $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)$ denote the spectrum as an element of $\mathcal A$,so that $\sigma(T)\subset \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T).$

We have to show the following three things:

$1$. boundary of  $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)=$ boundary of $\sigma(T)$.

$2$. If $T=T^*$, then $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)=\sigma(T)$. This part easily follows from part $1$
and the fact that $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb R$.

$3$. $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)=\sigma(T)$ for all $T\in \mathcal A$. This also follows easily because if $S=T-\lambda I$ is invertible in $\mathcal B(E)$,then $S^{-1}=S^*(SS^*)^{-1}\in \mathcal A$ since $SS^*$ is self-adjoint.(Using part $2$.)

So, I am only stuck  with part $1$.

These kind of topics are very new to me. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you actually need to show that
$$ \partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) = \partial \sigma(T) . $$
It would suffice to show that
$$\partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) \subseteq  \sigma(T)  \tag{$*$} $$
Then if $T=T^*$, you get that  $\partial \sigma _{\mathcal A} (T) \subseteq \sigma(T) \subseteq \mathbb R$ and so  $$\sigma _{\mathcal A} (T)  = \partial \sigma _{\mathcal A} (T)  \subseteq \sigma(T) \subseteq \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T).$$

To prove $(*)$, let $λ \in \partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)  .$   Pick a sequence $λ_n \notin \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) $ such that $λ_n \to λ$, so that $(T-\lambda_n)^{-1} \in \mathcal A$.  If it were the case that $\lambda \notin  \sigma(T)$ then   $(T-λ)^{-1} \in B(H)$, and   since inversion is continuous, $$(T-λ)^{-1} = \lim_n (T-λ_n)^{-1} \in \overline{\mathcal A} = \mathcal A .$$
So $λ \notin  \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)$, which is impossible since $λ\in \partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) $.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Since $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)$ is a subset of the real line, each of its points must be a boundary point. That is, $\sigma _{\mathcal A} (T)  = \partial \sigma _{\mathcal A} (T) $. This is due to the fact that  any subset of the real line must have emtpy interior in $\mathbb C$. [Recall that $\partial E= \overline{E} \setminus \operatorname{int} E$.]

Comment: The equality of boundaries is actually false in general: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679830/boundary-of-a-spectrum-proof

Comment: @Ruy But, we are talking about $C^*$ sub-algebra. Not any arbitrary banach sub-algebra.

Comment: @Evangelopoulos But, the book I am using claims that boundaries are actually equal in one of it's exercise.

Comment: @Evangelopoulos And why $\sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)=\partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T)$ ?

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar.  Allright.  Of course there is no counter-examples in C*-algebras, since the spectra agree.  But a Banach algebra counter-example indicates that the problem is a bit more delicate.

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar a subset of the real (or any) line has empty interior in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Yeah, fair enough. But I think it would be an interesting thing to show that boundaries are actually equal.

Comment: @SoumyadipSarkar Agreed! The above actually shows that $\partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) \subset \partial \sigma(T):$ Indeed, if $λ \in \partial \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) $ but $λ \notin \partial \sigma (T) $ then either $λ \notin \sigma(T) $ (which isn't the case) or $λ \in \operatorname{int} \sigma(T)$. But you can't have $B(λ,ε) \subset \sigma(T) $ for any $ε>0$ since $λ_n \in B(λ,ε)$ and $λ_n \notin \sigma_{\mathcal A}(T) \supseteq \sigma(T) $ for large $n$.